# jQuery image sliding up instead of sliding right

Tags: jquery, html

Basically my code is making this image slide up when I want it to slide to the right.  What's wrong with it?

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var scrollSpeed = 70;        // Speed in milliseconds
var step = 1;               // How many pixels to move per step
var current = 0;            // The current pixel row
var imageHeight = 4300;     // Background image height
var headerHeight = 300;     // How tall the header is.

//The pixel row where to start a new loop
var restartPosition = -(imageHeight - headerHeight);

function scrollBg(){

//Go to next pixel row.
current -= step;

//If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
if (current == restartPosition){
    current = 0;
}

//Set the CSS of the header.
$('#header').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");


}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/9FpvSBxm

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the value

```
function scrollBg(){

    //Go to next pixel row.
    current += step; //increment instead of decrement

    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition){
        current = 0;
    }

    //Set the CSS of the header.
    $('#header').css("background-position",current +"px 0"); // parameters are right top not top right



}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9NjjL/)

Answer (score 0):

Update:  I figured it out.

```
$('#header').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");
```

I changed the 0 to a 1 and it fixed it.  Now this was purely by luck, but why did that fix it?